# how many questions did D answer correctly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Each of A, B, C, and D took a test. Each of them answered at least one question correctly, and altogether they answered 67 questions correctly. A had more correct answers than anyone else. B and C together answered 43 questions correctly. How many correct answers did D have?

Comment: You could have used A,B,C,D instead of those long tedious names you know...

Comment: yeah please can you take them as that

Comment: I can, but I won't (as the majority of other users here). Please rephrase your question in a mathematical manner, instead of just copy-pasting it from your HW assignment. In addition, please share your insights, efforts, thoughts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**D answered 1 question correctly.**

```
A+B+C+D = 67
B+C = 43
A+43+D = 67
A+D = 24(Eqn 1)
Say B And C has 21 and 22 questions (21+22 = 43)

So A must answered more correct answers than A and B so he should answer minimum of 23 and so,

From Eqn 1,
23+D = 24 and

D = 1
```

B or C cannot answer more/less than these as the count of them have to include the rules.